# How to best organize URL authorizations in Spring security Java config

Tags: spring, security, url, spring-security, authorization

I have an application with a large number of URL authorizations declared. Probably over 200 of them. I have these configured with `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` in Java config as recommended by the spring security documentation. That being said, there are so many of them, that it becomes hard to maintain them in a single class.

I have come up with a solution that is currently working, but there's still a level of maintenance to it that's less than ideal. I'd like to know if others have ran into this issue and what solutions you have come up with.

**Current solution:**

Since there are so many URLs, I split them over several classes like so:

```
public class UrlConfig implements Customizer<ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer<HttpSecurity>.ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry> {

   @Override
    public void customize(ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer<HttpSecurity>.ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry requests) {
        buildUrlPartition().stream().forEachOrdered(config -> config.configure(requests));
    }

    SortedSet<UrlConfigSection> buildUrlPartition() {
        SortedSet<UrlConfigSection> urlPartition = new TreeSet<>();
        urlPartition.add(new CustomUrlsConfig());
        urlPartition.add(new DeleteUrlsConfig());
        urlPartition.add(new AddUrlsConfig());
        urlPartition.add(new EditUrlsConfig());
        urlPartition.add(new ListUrlsConfig());
        urlPartition.add(new CatchAllUrlsConfig());
        return urlPartition;
    }
}
```

This is adding all the split URL authorizations into a `SortedSet` and the order is mantained by having those URL classes extending an abstract class that will give them order. This customizer gets used in the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` like so:

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests(new UrlConfig())
            .formLogin()....
        ...
    }
}
```

The abstract class that mantains order is `UrlConfigSection`. The order is mantained so that more generic URL `something-something/**` paths don't get picked up before more specific `something-something/something` URL paths.

```
public abstract class UrlConfigSection implements Comparable<UrlConfigSection> {

    public abstract Integer getOrder();

    public abstract void configure(ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer<HttpSecurity>.ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry requests);

    public int compareTo(UrlConfigSection urlPartition) {
        return this.getOrder().compareTo(urlPartition.getOrder());
    }

    ... // implements the equals and hashcode methods. etc..
}
```

Example of a URL class is the following:

```
public class CatchAllUrlsConfig extends UrlConfigSection {

    @Override
    public Integer getOrder() {
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE; // this is so that it's always sorted as the last "catch all" urls.
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer<HttpSecurity>.ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry requests) {
        requests.antMatchers("sample url...").hasAnyAuthority("SOMEROLE");
        ..... // more declarations
    }
}
```

This is the catch all URL configuration, notice it will always be sorted as the last one. Other URL classes will have a specific number to them.

This is currently all working, however there's a certain maintenance aspect to this due to the ordering of the classes. Now I need to keep track of the numbers and where to place them in the sorted set. Is there a better way to do this? Has anyone run into a similar problem and how did you solve it?